# Establishing counts within inconsistent character strings in R?

Tags: r, string

I have a dataset that has survey respondents click an "all that apply" option for their preferences, and returns each option selected as one character string separated by commas.

So, some example responses might be:

- "Networking, Journals, Social Media Groups"
- "Journals"
- "Networking, Social Media Groups"
- "Networking,  Journals"

Is there a way to efficiently get a count for each sub-string that appear within the column? The desired output would be

```
 "Networking: 4"
 "Journals: 3"
 "Social Media Groups: 2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` alternative:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate(string = strsplit(as.character(string), ",")) %>% 
    unnest(string) %>% 
    count(String = str_trim(string))
```

```
String                  n
  <chr>               <int>
1 Journals                3
2 Networking              3
3 Social Media Groups     2
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(string = c("Networking, Journals, Social Media Groups", 
"Journals", "Networking, Social Media Groups", "Networking, Journals"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Running this as posted gives the error : "Error in count(., String = str_trim(string)) : 
  unused argument (String = str_trim(string))"

Comment: Have you loaded `tidyverse`. I can not reproduce the error. Version tidyverse_1.3.1.

Comment: Got it, for some reason relaunching R entirely instead of rm(list=ls()) to clear the environment was needed.

Answer (score 1):

### Data

```
df <- structure(list(string = c("Networking, Journals, Social Media Groups","Journals", "Networking, Social Media Groups", "Networking, Journals")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


# A tibble: 4 x 1
  string                                   
  <chr>                                    
1 Networking, Journals, Social Media Groups
2 Journals                                 
3 Networking, Social Media Groups          
4 Networking, Journals
```

### Code

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(string,sep = ", ") %>% 
  count(string)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  string                  n
  <chr>               <int>
1 Journals                3
2 Networking              3
3 Social Media Groups     2
```

Comment: Running this exactly as you posted leads to the error: "count(., string) : object 'string' not found".

Comment: In my example `df` is the name of my data.frame and `string` is the name of the column with the data. You need to change them to work to your data

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
table(unlist(strsplit(df$string, ",\\s+")))
```

-output

```
            Journals          Networking Social Media Groups 
                  3                   3                   2
```

#### data

````
df <- structure(list(string = c("Networking, Journals, Social Media Groups", 
"Journals", "Networking, Social Media Groups", "Networking, Journals"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))```
````